# Does setting up DKIM and SPF link reputations of the mail servers?

Tags: email, spf, dkim

I'd like to set up custom domain authentication using DKIM and SPF for our 3rd party email marketing company (like mail chimp or constant contact).  We also run MS exchange.  Our Exchange guy is convinced that setting up DKIM and SPF for email marketing company will forever tie the reputation of the email marketing company to our exchange server.  Is he correct?  If not, how do I convince him?

Comment: Where did you get the list you're going to send to? If it's a good list of people who opted-in then there's no need to be very concerned about the reputation of your own IP address and domain name. On the other hand, if the list is bad then the SPF and DKIM will have no effect on the reputation it would be the spam traps and other consequences of sending to a bad list that would be more useful to worry about.

Comment: It's a good list.  I believe his concern is ANY sender from mail chimp would affect our exchange server.  which is ludicrous to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have enough info now to make this an answer...

Yes, if this is a permission-based list that you have sent to recently (if it's old that means likely spam traps) then I think you are correct that there's not much risk at all.

One way to convince this person would be to find out what IP address your MailChimp emails originate from (maybe send to a small list with just yourself on it but a real send). And then check out the reputation of this IP address using the tools available such as MX Toolbox and others, then show him the output. I'd be surprised if your Mailchimp assigned IP address was on any blacklists or had reputation issues

When he says exchange server is he talking about your company *domain name* taking a reputation hit? Or is he worried about the IP address from which you send non-marketing email? If he's worried about a separate IP that you send day-to-day email from then explain to him that your marketing emails will go out from a Mailchimp assigned IP address. If he's worried about the domain two things: 1. Your list is opt-in and you've sent recently so it's not an issue 2. If it was a bad list that would cause your domain to be blacklisted then whether you have DMARC, SPF, and DKIM doesn't matter, the originating IP that sends spam can get blocked for spamming regardless.

So I think you are right here but it's a matter of making the case.